# PHP, set all $_POST to its own named variable

Tags: php, variables, post

on an PHP POST, is there a way of automatically setting each POST variable to its own named variable?

For example if I post

```
name = "henry"
age = "20"
location = "earth"
```

Instead of doing:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
```

is there a way of looping through all POST variables and setting it to the same named standard variable?

Comment: There is on PHP versions < 6.0.0 and it's called Register globals functionality, but it's strongly NOT recommended due to vulnerabilities.

Comment: Another solution is to use foreach loop through POST headers and set variables to it's values, `foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
  $$key = $value;  
}` , so something like that will output variables with $name, $age, $location and etc (I've used $_REQUEST for example)

Comment: D. Dimitrov, I tried the {$$key =$value;} method and it didn't seem to work.  Was I doing something wrong?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract function can help with this issue:

```
$_POST = ['foo' => 'bar'];
extract($_POST);
var_dump($foo) //returns 'bar'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to set $_POST variables programmatically. However, if you want it you can use [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php) function

```
 extract($_POST,EXTR_OVERWRITE,'prefix');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be use this:

```
if ($_POST) {

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        $name = "{$key}";
        $$name = $value;
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $name;
   }
echo "<pre>";
echo $name;
echo "<pre>";
echo $age;
echo "<pre>";
echo $location;
}
```